# Matlab Multiple Regression

Tags: algorithm, math, matlab, regression, polynomial-math

I have this set of variables:

```
N = 250;

% independent variables[0..10]
x_1 = rand(N,1) * 10;
x_2 = rand(N,1) * 10;

y = ones(N,1); % regresssion variable

y((x_1 + x_2 + rand(N,1) * 2) <= 11) = 2;
```

I want to make two-var regression in matlab, but do not know how to do this, can somebody helps me? The result of linear or polynomial regression must be line between this two classes, stored in y.

Comment: was the answer to your previous question :
http://stackoverflow.com/q/6796316/811335
 helpful?

Comment: yes, it was, but the problem is that I'm a newbie in matlab and I don't know english well to read book it'll take much time wich I haven't got. That's why I need some help.

Comment: did your try polyfit function? for e.g. y = polyfit(x1,x2,1)

Answer (score 1):

One or more 'independent' variables, it's the same. Just as an example few ways to solve:

```
>>> X= [x_1 x_2];
>>> X\ y
ans =
   0.10867
   0.11984

>>> pinv(X)* y
ans =
   0.10867
   0.11984
```

See more of [\](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mldivide.html) and [pinv](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/pinv.html).

Matlab do have many other ways to solve least squares. You may like to elaborate more on your specific case, in order to find the most suitable one. Anyway, above documentation is a good starting point for you.

**Edit**:
Some general information on `least squares` worthwhile to read are [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) and [mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/moler/leastsquares.pdf)

Comment: y - this is class label(1 or 2), I don't think it's correct to use it here without modifications. But what modifications should I make?

Comment: @Yekver: Firstly please refine your question (or make a new question). There is no indication that your question is related to classification. An simple ad hoc solution would be something like `y_hat= round([x_1 x_2]* b); y_hat(y_hat< 1)= 1; y_hat(y_hat> 2)= 2;`. Thanks